# Why does AirPlay disconnect when opening Pokemon Go?

Tags: ios, appletv, airplay, games, streaming

I use [Plex](https://www.plex.tv/apps/mobile/ios/) to watch TV/Movies (which stream from my home network) and I AirPlay it to my Apple TV. When AirPlaying, I have no problem navigating away to check my messages, etc.

However when I open *some* apps, usually games such as Pokemon Go (I like to wait for Pokemon while watching casual shows), it disconnects the AirPlay. Seconds later I hear my show playing through my phone speakers and I have to navigate to the Plex app to stop it.

Why does this happen and how can I prevent AirPlay from disconnecting?

Comment: I would wager it's something to do with the way Pokemon Go accesses the audio system on the phone and/or it's programmed to disallow use of AirPlay.

Comment: @tubedogg I have sounds turned off on the game and.. why would it disallow AirPlay? Why would it even do that?

Comment: You'd have to ask Niantic. They're the only ones that could answer that specific question (or your broader question in general) with any certainty.

Comment: @tubedogg Well I was asking why *would* they not why *do* they, to pick your brain for any reason you _think_ could be the case

Comment: I have no idea. It doesn't make much sense. The other thing is it may be a funky interaction between the apps - it isn't necessarily something done on purpose.